# How to position footer at the bottom of page and push it below content when the content increase

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky-footer

I am trying to position the footer on my page at the bottom of screen when there is not enough content. When Content height exceed above the screen height, I want the footer to fall under the content rather than stay fixed at the bottom.

I've tried a few ways mentioned on stackoverflow and other resources but not able to make it work.

I am currently following below link but not able to adapt it to my HTML structure

https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

HTML

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <header>
        Header
    </header>
    <div class="home-body-wrapper">
        Body
    </div>
    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>
</div>
```

Using Bootstrap +
Custom CSS

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.site-wrapper {
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #6cacc5;
   padding: 50px;
}
.site-wrapper header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
.site-wrapper .home-body-wrapper {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #c97874;
}
.site-wrapper footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfauxd6e/)

Comment: Why the downvote? I disagree about the question being too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `height: 100%` on `.site-wrapper` and replace it with `min-height: 100vh`. That way if the content is larger than the whole view port it'll get larger where as `height` limits the height completely.

Comment: yes this worked. But I have no idea why...and I've never worked with vh...will have to check if it works on all browsers..

Comment: A `vh` is very similar to `%` but it's relative to the viewport instead of the parent element. It's short for "viewport height".

Comment: I tried with % and it works same as vh. I updated the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tfauxd6e/1/  . ther is a big chunk overlapping..is this normal...do i have to handle this with padding bottom

Answer (score 0):

For my solution I removed the site-wrapper, made the body position relative, the body `min-height: 200px` and put a top and bottom padding on the content wrapper. The rest I basically left like in your code.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #6cacc5;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.home-body-wrapper {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #c97874;
  padding: 50px 0 200px 0; 
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #555555;
}
```

```html
<body>  
<header>
    Header
  </header>
  <div class="home-body-wrapper">

    <p>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies
      mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla.</p>

    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices
      mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

    <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>

    <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.</p>

    <p>Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>

    <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus.</p>

    <p>Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>

    <p>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies
      mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla.</p>

    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices
      mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: yea..I got it working without the site-wrapper...but I want it with it :-)